# Read undefined number of columns in csv with bash

Tags: bash, csv

Reading a CSV file with a Bash script is easy:

```
csvseparator=";"
while IFS="$csvseparator" read -r column1 column2 column3
do
    printf "%s - %s - %s\n" "$column1" "$column2" "$column3"
done < /path/to/csv_file.csv
```

But I have a problem, because I can't know the number of columns of the CSV file (maybe the first row has 3 columns, the second 10, the third 2, the fourth 50, ...).

One possible solution is divide the row by separator and add each column as an array value, but I think there'll be a better solution.
Is it possible read each column without knowing the number of columns of each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash is *not* particularly good at reading random CSV because you can't split on the separator if there are quoted fields.  For example,

```
"This,is,one,field","This is another"
```

contains two fields, and the unquoted comma separates them.

A CSV file is not well-formed if it does not contain the same number of columns on each row, anyway.

But the answer to your immediate question is probably to use an array.

```sh
while IFS='' read -r row; do
    readarray -d "$csvseparator" fields <<<"$row"
    printf "%i fields:\n" "${#fields[@]}"
    printf "%s\n" "${fields[@]}"
done <csvfile
```

If you don't want to use an array for whatever reason (perhaps your Bash is too old?), you can also simply use `set` to split into fields.

```sh
oldifs=$IFS
while IFS='' read -r row; do
    IFS=$csvseparator
    set -- $row
    IFS=$oldifs
    printf "%i fields:\n" "$#"
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
done <csvfile
```